# Closing Bootstrap's modal from Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I wrote a function (basing on some other I found on the Internet), which aids in displaying dynamically-generated modals without need to create ones in page's HTML.

To simplify code analysis, briefly:

- I add new binding handler to Knockout to allow disabling binding on specific element
- Modal is generated from a template using Mustache
- Mustache fills in relevant parts of the modal (title, body, buttons)
- Modal is wrapped in div, which stops data binding (`modalWrapper`)
- ... so that I can apply custom viewmodel to the modal with `ko.applyBindings`
- Buttons are generated automatically basing on description, like:

  ```
  {
      label: "OK",
      cssClass: "default",
      handler: "handleClick", // sets data-bind="click: handleClick"
      autoClose: true // adds data-dismiss="modal"
  }
  ```

Relevant parts of the code follows:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function () {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};

var modalTemplate = '<div class="modal fade">\
    <div class="modal-dialog {{size}}">\
        <div class="modal-content">\
            <div class="modal-header">\
                <h5 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h5>\
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>\
            </div>\
            <div class="modal-body">{{&body}}</div>\
            <div class="modal-footer">{{&buttons}}</div>\
        </div>\
    </div>\
</div>';

/**
 * Displays modal on the screen.
 * @param {Object} options Options
 * @param {string} options.title Title of the modal
 * @param {html} options.body Body of the modal
 * @param {string} options.size Size of the modal. Can be small, default, large or xlarge.
 * @param {Object} options.actions Describes buttons to display on the modal. For each, specify label, cssClass, handler and optionally autoClose.
 */
var showModal = function(options) {

    options = options || {};

    options = $.extend({
        title: '',
        body: '',
        size: false,
        actions: false,
        viewModel: {}
    }, options);

    var modalClass = {
        small: "modal-sm",
        default: "",
        large: "modal-lg",
        xlarge: "modal-xl"
    };

    var modalWrapper = $('<div data-bind="stopBinding: true"></div>').appendTo('body');

    var buttons;
    if (options.actions === false) {

        buttons = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>';
    } else {

        buttons = "";

        for (var i = 0, len = options.actions.length; i < len; i++) {

            var currentButton = $.extend({

                label: '&lt;No label&gt;',
                cssClass: 'default',
                handler: '',
                autoClose: true
            }, options.actions[i]);

            var btn = '<button type="button" class="btn ' +
                options.actions[i].cssClass +
                '" data-bind="click: ' +
                options.actions[i].handler +
                (options.actions[i].autoClose === true ? '" data-dismiss="modal"' : '')
                + '>'
                + options.actions[i].label
                + '</button>';

            buttons += btn;
        }
    }

    var templateData = {

        title: options.title,
        body: options.body,
        size: modalClass[options.size],
        buttons: buttons
    };

    var modalHtml = Mustache.render(modalTemplate, templateData);

    var $modal = $(modalHtml).appendTo(modalWrapper);

    $modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {

        modalWrapper.remove();
    });

    ko.applyBindings(options.viewModel, $modal.get()[0]);

    $modal.modal(options);
};
```

I have a problem with this autoclosing feature. If it is on, viewmodel processes the click, modal is closed by Bootstrap mechanisms and then removed from DOM after hiding.

But when I want a button to be non-auto-closing, I have no means to close modal from the viewmodel. The solution I thought of was to inject a method to viewmodel like:

```
viewmodel['close'] = function() { $modal.modal('hide'); };
```

However this seems to be a hackish solution (even for Javascript ;)). Similarly, I may inject the `$modal` itself to the viewmodel, but that would be even more ugly.

What would be then the best way to close the modal from within modal's viewmodel?

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar requirement by assigning an *(auto-generated)* `id` to the modal `div` tag.

```
var modalId = ('modal' + Math.random()).replace('.', '');
var modalTemplate = '<div class="modal fade" id="' + modalId + '">'\ // remaining code here
```

Then, that `id` is being passed to viewmodel, which allows it to close the corresponding modal via

```
$('#' + _self.modalId).modal('hide');
```

A comparable event subscription to `'hidden.bs.modal'` handles the cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom Knockout binding for handling the visibility of the modal.
This binding connects the bound modal element to the supplied model observable. Click handlers in the model now only have to manage this observable to control the modal visibility.

You could apply this binding for example in your `modalTemplate` variable: `` var modalTemplate = `<div class="modal fade" data-bind="bootstrapModalVisible: yourObservable">\ ``...

I haven't incorporated the binding in your case, but below is an example of the working of this binding.

- the modalVisible observable is initialized to true, so the modal immediately shows
- the close button immediately hides the modal by setting the observable to false
- the upper-right close button closes the modal because of `data-dismiss="modal"`. The event handlers in the binding's `init` will make sure the correct state is written to the observable.
- the save button only closes the modal when confirmed, showing the possibility to postpone closing the modal

```js
ko.bindingHandlers['bootstrapModalVisible'] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { valueAccessor()(false); })
      $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function () { valueAccessor()(true); })
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
      if (ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())) {
          $(element).modal('show');
      } else {
          $(element).modal('hide');
      }
    }
};

function Test() {
  var self = this;
  self.modalVisible = ko.observable(true);
  self.showModal = function() {
    self.modalVisible(true);
  };
  self.hideModal = function() {
    self.modalVisible(false);
  };
  self.save = function() {
    if (window.confirm('Close modal?')) {
      self.modalVisible(false);
    }
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new Test());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: showModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" data-bind="bootstrapModalVisible: modalVisible">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Example modal</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bind="click: hideModal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: save">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```